# Why am I randomly losing Research Points?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

While playing Game Dev Tycoon, I realised that my Research points are randomly disappearing. I had 102 points and suddenly, it jumped down to only 50? Why is this happening?

Comment: I think we might need more information here. What actions are in progress when that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many uses for Research points (topics, features), but the easiest to overlook is training.

You should consider the RP cost when training.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @shanodin it totally does answer the question.  it's very easy to miss the RP cost of training.  That should be the first place to change the way the player is playing the game.  From personal experience.

Comment: Your edit clears things up nicely

Comment: I have selected your answer as the correct one, only because it has slightly more details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I did not realize that research points have uses. It is used to research new topics, game features, and other special perks. The game features can then be implemented into a custom engine, which available for research near the start of the game. Upon researching, your Research Points (RP) will decrease.

Comment: Didn't the tutorial tell you the use of Research Points?  Also you don't research new engines :D

Comment: @Darakath Fixed